# Adding "comparable app available" note

Tags: android, google-play

At google play, facebook messenger app page, there is a note of `comparable app available` that is diverting the user to the `lite` edition, same thing available in the lite edition, that divert the user to the standard edition, as shown below.

How can I add such thing between my apps? or it is done automatically by google play?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm following this too. Looks like it's new feature but it's only available for big developers such as Facebook. I think Google itself place this label and it is not controllable by developer. I searched on google but there is no official document and announcement for this feature yet.